# Realtek r8125 2.5Gbps Ubuntu 16.04 only getting 1.25Gbps speeds

Tags: networking, 16.04, drivers, realtek

I just installed my realtek r8125 NIC into my ubuntu 16.04 server and connected it to a QNAP QSW-1105-5T Switch and then to my Windows machine which also has a realtek r8125 NIC.

However the speeds are only 160MBps, I was expecting much higher speeds:
here is the Ubuntu machine:

```
@MediaServer:~$ sudo uname -a
Linux MediaVault 4.4.0-209-generic #241-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 13 01:06:06 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

@MediaServer:ethtool enp30s0
Settings for enp30s0:
        Supported ports: [ TP ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
                                2500baseX/Full
        Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
                                2500baseX/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Speed: 2500Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: Twisted Pair
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
        MDI-X: Unknown
Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: Operation not permitted
        Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                               drv probe ifdown ifup
        Link detected: yes
@MediaServer: lspci -knn |grep Eth

1e:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:8125]
        Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:0123]
        Kernel driver in use: r8125
        Kernel modules: r8125
1f:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:8125]
        Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:0123]
        Kernel driver in use: r8125
        Kernel modules: r8125
@MediaServer:~$ modinfo r8125
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-209-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/realtek/r8125.ko
version:        9.005.01-NAPI
license:        GPL
description:    Realtek RTL8125 2.5Gigabit Ethernet driver
author:         Realtek and the Linux r8125 crew <netdev@vger.kernel.org>
srcversion:     ED7801579D65D476553804B
alias:          pci:v000010ECd00003000sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000010ECd00008125sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:
retpoline:      Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-209-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
parm:           speed_mode:force phy operation. Deprecated by ethtool (8). (uint)
parm:           duplex_mode:force phy operation. Deprecated by ethtool (8). (uint)
parm:           autoneg_mode:force phy operation. Deprecated by ethtool (8). (uint)
parm:           advertising_mode:force phy operation. Deprecated by ethtool (8). (uint)
parm:           aspm:Enable ASPM. (int)
parm:           s5wol:Enable Shutdown Wake On Lan. (int)
parm:           s5_keep_curr_mac:Enable Shutdown Keep Current MAC Address. (int)
parm:           rx_copybreak:Copy breakpoint for copy-only-tiny-frames (int)
parm:           use_dac:Enable PCI DAC. Unsafe on 32 bit PCI slot. (int)
parm:           timer_count:Timer Interrupt Interval. (int)
parm:           eee_enable:Enable Energy Efficient Ethernet. (int)
parm:           hwoptimize:Enable HW optimization function. (ulong)
parm:           s0_magic_packet:Enable S0 Magic Packet. (int)
parm:           tx_no_close_enable:Enable TX No Close. (int)
parm:           enable_ptp_master_mode:Enable PTP Master Mode. (int)
parm:           debug:Debug verbosity level (0=none, ..., 16=all) (int)


@MediaServer:~$ sudo hdparm -tT /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
 Timing cached reads:   19098 MB in  1.99 seconds = 9575.62 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 624 MB in  3.01 seconds = 207.38 MB/sec
administrator@MediaVault:~$ sudo hdparm -tT /dev/mapper/
control     cryptswap1  Enc5

@MediaServer:~$ sudo hdparm -tT /dev/mapper/Enc5

/dev/mapper/Enc5:
 Timing cached reads:   19454 MB in  1.99 seconds = 9755.55 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 1496 MB in  3.00 seconds = 498.29 MB/sec
```

The main disk is an old SSD although im actually getting data from the Enc5 raid 5 disks that can easily push 500MB/sec

Am I missing something with the drivers or setup that might improve the speed ?

doing  `sudo lshw -class network`
Capacity is only 1GBPS how do I fix it?

shows:

```
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:1e:00.0
       logical name: enp30s0
       version: 00
       serial: 00:13:3b:b0:2f:a2
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8125 driverversion=9.005.01-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.0.10 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:19 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f8000000-f800ffff memory:f8010000-f8013fff memory:f8020000-f802ffff memory:f8030000-f809ffff memory:f80a0000-f80bbfff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:1f:00.0
       logical name: enp31s0
       version: 00
       serial: 00:13:3b:b0:2f:a3
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8125 driverversion=9.005.01-NAPI latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:19 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f8100000-f810ffff memory:f8110000-f8113fff memory:f8120000-f812ffff memory:f8130000-f819ffff memory:f81a0000-f81bbfff
```

Comment: Looks like your kernel is seeing it as 2 separate cards.  Ubuntu 16.04 LTS will go EoL very shortly here if it already hasn't.  Have you tried a Live CD/DVD/USB of a newer version of Ubuntu with a newer kernel in it to see if it sees that card as 1?

Comment: It is a dual port NIC.
I tried booting into Ubuntu 20.04, it only was about the same speed (168MBPS)